# Determine array size

Tags: excel, vba

I currently facing a problem on how to determine the size of array after looping ends. Below is my coding for that particular function.

```
Function analyse(ByVal work_date As Date, time As String, action As String, decision As Boolean, branch As String) As String
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim att_time(6) As String
    Dim dated(1) As Date
    Set sh = Worksheets("shifthr")

    lastrec = sh.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    a = 1
    For i = 2 To lastrec
        dated(a) = work_date
        If branch = sh.Cells(i, 1) Then
            att_time(a) = time
            a = a + 1
        End If
    Next i
    If att_time(a) = 4 Then

    ElseIf att_time(a) = 6 Then

    End If
End Function
```

Thanks for you guys helping hands. Appreciate it very much

Comment: Size of the array? But you already declared the size of the array?

Comment: @SiddharthRout, after the looping is done, I want to detect how much the data had been saved in the array and from that need do some analysis on it. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: I thought so :) See my answer.

Comment: Thanks so much. I try onto it. Later let you know ya. :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could alter your dim statement to dimension your initial array as () and then use redim preserve as you are looping "a" to increase the count - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8k3cys2.aspx.

If you want to find out the size of the array, you could use ubound(arrayname). http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/95b8f22f(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 0):

> I currently facing a problem on how to determine the size of array after looping ends.

You have already declared the size of the array in your dim statement. I guess you want to find the number of elements in the array? If yes, then try this (**UNTESTED**) Also I guess you wanted to keep `dated(a) = work_date` inside the `IF` Condition? If not then you don't need to use `a` to fill the `dated(a) = work_date`. Also I don't think you need a `Function` for this as you are not returning any value to `analyse`. Use a `Sub`

```
Sub analyse(ByVal work_date As Date, time As String, _
action As String, decision As Boolean, branch As String)
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim att_time() As String
    Dim dated() As Date
    Dim a As Long
    Dim boolCheck As Boolean

    Set sh = Worksheets("shifthr")

    lastrec = sh.Range("C" & sh.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    a = 1

    For i = 2 To lastrec 
        If branch = sh.Cells(i, 1) Then
            ReDim Preserve dated(a)
            ReDim Preserve att_time(a)

            dated(a) = work_date
            att_time(a) = time

            a = a + 1

            boolCheck = True
        End If
    Next i

    If boolCheck = True Then
        Debug.Print UBound(dated)
        Debug.Print UBound(att_time)

        'OR

        Debug.Print a - 1
    Else
        Debug.Print "No Matching records found"
    End If
End Sub
```